# Matplotlib animate objects with different markers

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I need to do an animation in matplotlib where I want to plot a moving particle (as a point) and a line (corresponding to the magnitude and direction of its speed)

I have taken a look at this website,were there are ifferent examples of animations.

https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

Basically what they do in the examples is initializing `line` as a plot with certain markers:

```
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o')  # for points
line2, = ax.plot([], [], '-')  # for lines
```

and in the `animate` function they just use `set_data` to update the position of the particle for the next frame
    def animate(i):
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,

However in the examples, they either use lines (eg: the pendulum example) OR dots (the particles in a box example), but not both.

How can I first plot the particle as a dot and then add a speed vector as a line?

The animate function has to return `line` so if I use `line` and `line2` I need a way to merge them.

Something like:

```
plot(x, y, 'o')                  # position
plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], '-')  # speed
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define two "lines", one which consists of marked points, but no lines in between (`ls=""`) and one with only a line but no markers (`marker=""`)

```
points, = ax.plot([1,2], [3,4], marker='o', ls="" )  # for points
line,   = ax.plot([2,1], [4,3], marker="" , ls="-")  # for lines
```

The animate function would then return both "lines":

```
def animate(i):
    # x = ...; y = ...
    line.set_data(x, y)
    # x2 = ...; y2 = ...
    points.set_data(x2, y2)
    return points, line
```

Comment: But the animate function should return a single object. How do I merge both?

Comment: Well, you have to return both as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: I cannot thank enough for this answer! I couldn't find any way to change markers in a scatter plot. Thank you!